# how to change cursor style by positon in website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, cursor

i have a website and my website can scroll according to mouse position. I mean when cursor near to bottom then website scroll down and when near top it scroll up. but i want to display down and up arrow when cursor near the top or bottom.

Comment: Use the cursor style in css and change it depending on the div being hovered over?

Comment: thanks for your attention, it s really good advice to use two fixed element on the top and bottom with transparency. But it i am waiting for more healthy answer ))

Comment: healthy answer? it’s a valid approach and needs no JS. Maybe consider it?

Comment: Gidromasservis, do you use jQuery , if then you can check my code thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using mousemove on document.body

```
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  if (e.screenY < topThreshhold) {
    //change the cursor to up arrow
    document.body.style.cursor = "n-resize";
  } else if (e.screenY > bottomThreshhold) {
    //change the cursor to down arrow
  }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: topThreshhold is not defined in second line

Comment: @GidromasservisQSC that’s for you to define.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it depending on how far down the user has scrolled, you can use this code

```
const change_cursor_height = 500;

window.onscroll = function() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop >= change_cursor_height) {
        document.body.style.cursor = "n-resize";
    } else {
        document.body.style.cursor = "auto";
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this needs a mousemove trigger, not a scroll trigger